# How to use wcf webservice from javaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, sql, wcf

We would like to use the same WCF web service to be used from JavaScript. How is this done. We want to access database from JavaScript through WCF web service. In two different domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the solution and is given below.

http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery

### Asp page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#getCustomers').click(function () {
            var $customersList = $('#customersList');
            $customersList.empty().appendLi('Loading...');
            // Get the JsonP data  $.getJSON('http://localhost:65025/CustomersService.svc/GetCustomers?callback=?', { id: '25' }, function (customers) {
                alert('Received ' + customers.length + ' Customers');

                alert("data -" + JSON.stringify(customers.toString()));
                $customersList.empty();
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    $customersList.appendLi(this.Name + " - " + this.Email);
                });
            });
        }); // end #getCustomer.click

    });

    (function($) {
        $.fn.appendLi = function(text) {
            /// <summary>
            /// This is a simple helper plugin on top of the append() function that allows you to quickly add a li
            ///     element with text.
            /// </summary>
            return $(this).each(function() {
                $(this).append($('<li />').text(text));
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Web.config in WCF hosted place

```
<bindings>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"         crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>

</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<services>

  <service name="CustomersService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="CustomersServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IAT.Web.Services.CustomersService" />
  </service>

  <service name="ServiceSite.CustomersService">
  </service>

</services>
```

### CustomersService.svc

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Display(int id)
    {
        string[] s = new string[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            s[i] = i + "*" + (i + 1) + "*" + (i + 2);
        }

        return string.Format(id.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple JavaScript ping function I use to connect to a WCF service - basicHttpbinding w/ SOAP message and a DataContract. From something like this, you should be able to adapt to your own requirements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Ping() {             
  //set up varable
   var sContent;
   sContent=  "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><a:TextSection><Method>ping</Method></a:TextSection><a:BodySection>AA==</a:BodySection></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

  var xmlhttp =  new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('POST', Demo.URL.value, true);  

  //    alert(Demo.URL.value);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4||xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
    //alert("Ready state: " + xmlhttp.readyState.toString());
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        //alert("good");
        Demo.pingresponse.value = "Response: " +xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
        if (xmlhttp.status !=200){
            //alert("bad");
            Demo.pingresponse.value = "Error: " +xmlhttp.status.toString() +"  response text:  " +xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    } else {
       //alert("readystate bad");
    }
}
//send request    
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("POST http:localhost:8085/ServiceClass/ServiceMethod HTTP/1.1"); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("VsDebuggerCausalityData","iEA8ACQAA"); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","\"http://NameSpace\""); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Host","localhost:8085"); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Expect","100-continue"); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate"); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection","Keep-Alive"); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length","639");                   
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
        xmlhttp.send(sContent);                  
}
</Script>
```